# Start working with audio API with Web : Code is working is desktop browser but not working in mobile browser

Tags: javascript, dom-events, audio-streaming, getusermedia, ws

Below given code is for recording audio from browser and play at the same moment. My problem is this code is working on desktop browser but not working on mobile browser using Chrome browser in both platform with latest version. Can any one help me with this?

```
<audio id="player" controls></audio>
<script>
  const player = document.getElementById('player');

  const handleSuccess = function(stream) {

    if (window.URL) {
      player.srcObject = stream;
    } else {
      player.src = stream;
    }
  };

  navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ audio: true, video: false })
      .then(handleSuccess);
</script>
```

Comment: can you give me more description about your source code, so I will help you.

Comment: It has to be initiated by a user event like a click.  Also making it work reliably across platforms is hard, be ready to roll up your sleeves.

Comment: @Dipakchavda Thanks for help but i got the answer actually navigator wont work without ssl in mobile browser. i installed ssl to localhost and now it is working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia` will not work without SSL in mobile browser so I have installed SSL on my localhost and now it is working.

Comment: In fact, it won't work on desktop browsers either.  Glad you found the solution!